# GPG : find secret keys expiration date

Tags: key, gnupg

I'm new with GPG but reading GPG documentation the only thing that do not seems clear to me is if when a couple of keys were generated, there's a way to find if the private one has an expiration date.

Please consider that I'm working with not default keyring because secring/pubring are stored into docker container / Openshift.

Thanks in advance.